# Pycharm Interpreter - transfer the .exe file from one computer to another

Tags: pycharm, interpreter

im new in Pycharm and my interpreter located in remote (we are sharing the same interpreter from the same path)
the issue is that the remote is down, and in one PC i dont have internet connection nither. i want to find a way to transfar all my interpreters setting from one PC to another.

The first PC which contains all interpreters setting has internet connection so I download all packages manualy so now I have all packages I need in this PC but I can't do the same to the second PC because it dosent have internet connection.

i want to find a way to transfar all my interpreters setting from one PC to another.

Comment: Use any online cloud storage service, and download it on the target system?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to just copy exe files to get python running is not a good idea, because its not only about copying the right files: its about setting the environment variables correctly, setting up the permissions correctly and putting the libraries in the correct places. if you are new to python, don't bother with it.

here is a simple way:

1. download the python binary installer from python.org: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.3/python-3.11.3-amd64.exe (don't run it, just download)
2. copy the binary installed from the internet-connected computer to the other one.
3. Run the binary on the target computer.

Comment: Hi Gal, thanks for your response.  Im not sure I understand how the path work , is it replace all the missing packages ? my second PC contains Python and Pycharm and already used it, but now the remote is down so all my packeges are missing because they're located in remote.